# Can't Run Hello Vapor Project on Xcode

Tags: xcode, vapor

I'm trying to follow the [vapor tutorial](https://vapor.github.io/documentation/getting-started/hello-world.html), but I'm having a problem running Hello World project in Xcode.

I typed "`vapor new Hello`", "`cd Hello`", "`vapor xcode`" in terminal.

I pressed y to open in xcode.

In xcode, when I clicked run, it builds but doesn't run. Nothing in the debug console.

When I executed "vapor run" in the terminal, it runs though.

I have Xcode 8.3.2, Swift 3.1, Vapor Toolbox 2.0.3, Vapor Framework 2.0.0.

Is there a step I missed in Xcode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to check Run for the scheme in the toolbar. As a default, it's not checked.

Comment: FY: A [mini screen capture⇗](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/issues/1038) could also be helpful in the answer here.

Comment: It's worth noting that the toolbox mentions to `Select the 'Run' scheme to run.` when generating Xcode projects.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select and set "My Mac" in Run scheme

[image]